# ターミナルで色々作業をしているとlsの出力が崩れて元に戻らなくなることがある

Tags: tmux

[image: 現象発生時の画面]

**環境**
ホストOS Windows10 64bit
ゲストOS(Vagrant + VirtualBox) Ubuntu16.04
ターミナル (Mintty 2.8.2 (MSYS2))
tmux 2.1 (ゲストOS)

上記の環境で稀に画像のようにlsの表示が崩れることがあります(上は異常なPane, 下は正常なPane)。一度こうなると一旦該当のPainをkillするしか現象が改善されません。

何が原因なのか不明なのですが、なんとなく不正な制御シーケンスを入力してしまった時のような気がしています。こういう場合、Paneのkill, 再作成以外で復帰できる方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

原因にも依りますが[`reset`コマンド](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/util-linux/man1/reset.1.html)で復旧できませんか？

Comment: 復旧しました！ありがとうございます。 resetコマンド覚えておきます